# Why is the IncomingNumber always empty?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm totally new to mobile programming and to Xamarin or Xamarin.Forms. So I thought about starting small and trying a first app that is showing the phone number of an incoming call (just to know how to get this information into my app).

After a lot of trying and searching the net and not finding appropriate answers, I managed to at least be able to hit break points when there's an incoming call.

For that I created a class called `StateListener` in the Android specific project of my Xamarin.Forms solution. This class looks like that:

```
public class StateListener : PhoneStateListener
{
    public override void OnCallStateChanged(CallState state, string incomingNumber)
    {
        base.OnCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        switch (state)
        {
            case CallState.Ringing:
                break;   // <== set break point here
            case CallState.Offhook:
                break;
            case CallState.Idle:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And I instantiated this class in my `MainActivity`'s `OnCreate` method like this:

```
StateListener phoneStateListener = new StateListener();
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);
telephonyManager.Listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListenerFlags.CallState);
```

Now, when I run my little solution then the break point (see comment in code) is hit, but unfortunately the `incomingNumber` of the `OnCallStateChanged` method is always empty.

Following the unsatisfying documentation about the `OnCallStateChanged` method I set the needed  `Permission.ReadPhoneState` permission in the manifest file, but that didn't help.

Maybe you can?

Comment: run on emulator or real device?

Comment: Run on emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that once you emulated your app you have to set any new permissions manually inside the emulated Android, your app won't ask for it, since it's already installed.
After I gave my app the "Phone" permissions inside the emulated Android and restarted my app, I got the `incomingNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

As [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html?authuser=2&hl=id#onCallStateChanged(int,%20java.lang.String)) says:

> If application does not have READ_CALL_LOG permission or carrier
>   privileges (see TelephonyManager.hasCarrierPrivileges()), an empty
>   string will be passed as an argument.

so please check your application permissions.

Comment: I followed [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Telephony.PhoneStateListener.OnCallStateChanged/p/Android.Telephony.CallState/System.String/) Xamarin documentation talking about the `Permission.ReadPhoneState` permission, and I added this permission to the manifest file

Comment: I see, maybe you could try add READ_CALL_LOG permission and test on real device.

Comment: I not own a real device yet, but I try to add the permission you mentioned to the manifest file, maybe this helps.